# Normalization of sinus harmonics

Tags: integration

I've had several problems while trying to solve the following normalization problem:

$$\int_0^\pi  \sin^{(2l+1)} \theta\ d\theta $$

The solution to this is given as:

$$ \frac {2\cdot(2^l l!)^2}{(2l+1)!}$$

but when I tried getting there with reduction or integration by parts I failed both times. 
Hints towards a way of solving it or explaining the way are both appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried a proof by induction?

Comment: No, the answer was provided because there are other parts of the task so I just want to calculate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using the [Beta Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi\sin^{2l+1}(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta
&=-2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2l}(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\cos(\theta)\\
&=2\int_0^1\left(1-u^2\right)^l\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_0^1\left(1-u\right)^lu^{-1/2}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(l+1)\,\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(l+3/2)}\\
&=\frac{2^{2l+1}l!\,l!}{(2l+1)!}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Integration By Parts**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi\sin^{2l+1}(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta
&=-\int_0^\pi\sin^{2l}(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\cos(\theta)\\
&=2l\int_0^\pi\cos^2(\theta)\sin^{2l-1}(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=2l\int_0^\pi\sin^{2l-1}(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta-2l\int_0^\pi\sin^{2l+1}(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac{2l}{2l+1}\int_0^\pi\sin^{2l-1}(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac{2l}{2l+1}\frac{2l-2}{2l-1}\cdots\frac23\int_0^\pi\sin(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac{2^ll!}{(2l+1)!!}\,2\\
&=\frac{2^ll!\,2^ll!}{(2l+1)!}\,2\\
&=\frac{2^{2l+1}l!\,l!}{(2l+1)!}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Beat me to it :)